# Sum of even numbers from n to m regardless if n<m or n>m

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to calculate the sum of numbers from `n` to `m`, regardless if `n>m` or `n<m`. I've only managed to get it to work while `n<m`.
Can someone give me a hand/hint please?

```
       function SumEvenN()
{
    var n = getFirstNumber();
    var m = getSecondNumber();

    var s = 0;

    if (n<m)
    {
        min = n;
        max = m;
    }
    else if (m<n)
    {
        min = m;
        max = n;
    }

    if (n>m)
    {
        [n, m] = [m, n]
    }
    for (var i = 2; i<=m; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            s += i;
        }
    }
    alert(s);

}


function getFirstNumber()
{
    var a = document.getElementById("first-number");    
    return parseInt(a.value);
}

function getSecondNumber()
{
    var b = document.getElementById("second-number");   
    return parseInt(b.value);
}
```

Comment: Looks like homework. We don't do homework here. You have to try something first

Comment: Add a code snippet of what you have so far

Comment: Hint: you're figuring out the min and max, but then you're not using them. You should use them.

Comment: This can even be reduced to a simple mathematical equation, eliminating the need for loop

Comment: what are `getFirstNumber` and `getSecondNumber`? What do they do? Surely you should get your 2 numbers from arguments to the function?

Comment: getFirstNumber and getSecondNumber are from user input. edited initial post to see full code

Comment: i think i solved it by adding:  if (n>m)
 {
  [n, m] = [m, n]
 }. Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
function SumEvenN(n,m) {
  if(n>m) [n, m] = [m, n];  // swap variables if n>m
  n=n%2 ? n+1 : n;          // if n is odd add 1 to it
  m=m%2 ? m-1 : m;          // if m is odd add -1 to it
  let t=(m-n+2)/2;          // number of even elements between n and m
  return t*(n+m)/2;         // use formula of arithmetic progression sum
}
```

```js
function SumEvenN(n,m) {
  if(n>m) [n, m] = [m, n];  // swap variables if n>m
  n=n%2 ? n+1 : n;          // if n is odd add 1 to it
  m=m%2 ? m-1 : m;          // if m is odd add -1 to it
  let t=(m-n+2)/2;          // number of even elements between n and m
  return t*(n+m)/2;         // use foruma of arithmetic progression sum
}

function calc() {
  console.log(SumEvenN(+first.value, +second.value) );
}
```

```html
<input id="first" type="number" value="9"/>
<input id="second" type="number" value="16"/>
<button id="btn" onclick="calc()">Calc</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless that this could be a much simpler math equation, your problem is this line:

`for (var i = 2; i<=m; i++)`

Instead, use the min and max that you found above:

`for (var i = min; i <= max; i++)`

```js
const getFirstNumber = () => 9;
const getSecondNumber = () => 4;

function SumEvenN() {
  var n = getFirstNumber();
  var m = getSecondNumber();

  var s = 0;

  if (n<m)
  {
      min = n;
      max = m;
  }
  else if (m<n)
  {
      min = m;
      max = n;
  }
  for (var i = min; i <= max; i++)
  {
      if (i % 2 == 0)
      {
          s += i;
      }
  }
  alert(s);

}

SumEvenN();
```

Comment: The `else` does not need `if (m<n)` because if  n<m is false m<=n must be true so it doesn't need testing.

Comment: You could test if min is odd or even. if even then i = min else i = min+1. Then the summation loop can become simpler and faster. Just step in 2s from the first even number.
`while ( i <= max)
{
    s += i;
    i += 2;
}`

Comment: @pjaj the whole algorithm is unnecessary but I think it's more useful to directly show them why their code wasn't working as written rather than showing them a better way altogether in this case, since they're clearly a beginner

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, Not only should we be helping bug fix, but there should be an element of education as well. There's little point in letting bad practice go unmarked. Beginners are not going to get better if they are not shown how. But this is completely off topic.

Comment: Then at that point why stop at changing the if to an if/else? Why not just throw ternaries in there, change their `== 0` check to treating 0 as falsy... The reason is because it's overload of information since while each of these are trivial to us they are all logical steps that don't contribute to answering the question they asked but do make it harder to understand exactly what they did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) for getting the min and max values.

Then take a sinlge lopp from min to max value by using the first even number and iterate until the value is greater than the max value.

Add the value to the sum.

```js
function sumEven(a, b) {
    var min = Math.min(a, b),
        max = Math.max(a, b),
        value,
        sum = 0;
        
    for (value = min + min % 2; value <= max; value += 2) {
        sum += value;
    }
    
    return sum;
}

console.log(sumEven(1, 5)); //  6
console.log(sumEven(5, 1)); //  6
console.log(sumEven(2, 8)); // 20
console.log(sumEven(8, 2)); // 20
```